# URL Rewritng on local Ubuntu server is not working

Tags: linux, .htaccess, ubuntu, url-rewriting

Recently i have installed ubuntu 12.10 on my system. Installed apache 2.0, php,mysql,etc.
Also enabled url rewriting by "sudo a2enmod rewrite". Also edited the configuration file to change  AllowOverride none to  AllowOverride All.

Here is my .htaccess file

```
 RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine^M
    RewriteRule    ^blog?$    blog.php?p=$1    [NC,L]    
    RewriteRule    ^blog/([a-z0-9A-Z]+)/?$    blog.php?p=$1    [NC,L]   
    RewriteRule    ^appstore?$    appstore.php    [NC,L]
    RewriteRule    ^appstore/([a-z0-9A-Z\--]+)/?$  
    RewriteRule    ^([a-z]+)/?$    index.php?p=$1    [NC,L]    

Now ideally, site-url/blog should display the result of blog.php,
site-url/appstore should display the result of appstore.php
```

and rest all should display the result of index.php.
But I am not getting the desired result. What can be the problem?

P.S : Earlier I was testing my application on windows 7 Xampp server and it was working perfectly. It is also working prefectly on Amazon ec2 instance where I have installed ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have option `MultiViews` enabled. Disable it using this line at the top of your root .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Adding above line in .htaccess gave 500 internal server error. But your guess was correct. Multiviews option was enabled. So I just disabled it in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default. It working perfectly now :) Thanks a lot for the help :)